# Typescript function inside generic interface to infer argument type

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an interface that accepts a generic:

```
interface ObjectKey<T extends {}>{
   key: keyof T
   doSomethingWithKey: (value: any) => void
}
```

Using it like this:

```
interface User {
   name: string,
   age: number,
   archived: boolean
}

const nameKey: ObjectKey<User> = {
   key: 'name', 
   doSomethingWithKey: (value) => console.log(value) // I want to infer value type here
}
```

As mentioned above i want to infer the 'value' argument type. Something like this:

```
interface ObjectKey<T extends {}>{
   key: keyof T
   doSomethingWithKey: (value: T[key]) => void
}
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried something like:

```
interface ObjectKey<T extends {}>{
   key: keyof T
   doSomethingWithKey: (value: { [Property in keyof T]: T[Property] }[keyof T]) => void
}
```

But it returns all available types of T. For example if we use User interface, 'value' argument would be 'string | number | boolean'

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgNIQCeAPACrIQAekIAJgM7IDeAvgHxMBQyPA1kQC5k-QgHsYyUtx4B6GclqiAyqIC2EMAAtQAcwDqwLQUJCAFADc4AGwCuEIXBCEAlMgC8bZOdHBa0hcpqGtog+oaaxmaWtvbMANoAClCiAA7QYITIoMJE4pIAukKkiclpUBn5LHEieaT5rh5ePn4snJygkLCIKACq9NDM-iBw6kL0YFC6ADT+cDqxIDaq6NAzPMhwUAja5hC0QuiiolYQjpytnAiiIOPIw+qRaFg4+ETEfdCeboPrIkIA5PcIP8psh-IoVOotLoDEZBMgLNY7A1PFcbscIAA6KyiHSImKuOTIADCmhwvGQ-2idn+yAyaWQZKgEHOQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make `ObjectKey` a union type of all possible combinations by mapping over the object keys

```
type ObjectKey<T extends {}> = {
   [K in keyof T]: {
      key: K, 
      doSomethingWithKey: (value: T[K]) => void
   }
}[keyof T]

interface User {
   name: string,
   age: number,
   archived: boolean
}

const nameKey: ObjectKey<User> = {
   key: 'age', 
   doSomethingWithKey: (value) => console.log(value)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AaQiAPAFShAD2AgDsATAZygG8BfAPigF4aAoKDgbTSgEsSoAa0wB7AGZQcAXQBcbDgqGY5aADRR2iqGREBlEQFsIwABb8A5gHVepjCDkAKAG4BDADYBXCHJzcpASmZGJxFeMk0oWlZaTmEQcUkpVlZ%20YgAnMRdkaABVCgg0%20Q4SFyM5CmA0i1UIl3NvKBIPAzgCmoUXNOQzJwgyOTgRETcIFxJo5NBIKAAxIeZYRBR0TCw8gvoAblYAeh2FAD0AfmTkERIKxtKIOzl4JFQ7Nfy0xhZqCLi5AHI6iG-1BEdPojKYLNZbMooM53F5AkxGGcLsMIAA6NwicwwzwQfzRIA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been struggling with this. Could you explain what does the '[typeof K]' at the end of the type declaration actually do ?

Comment: @thanossav First we created a mapped type with the same keys as the passed type T and values equal to the valid object for that key.  The `[keyof T]` at the end is known as an indexed access type, if you index a type with it's own keys (`T[keyof T]`) you get a union of all it's values - in this case a union of all valid objects types for all keys

Comment: oooh i see. so when we 'iterate' the keys of T, we are creating a new object with its key being the current keyof T, and then we throw off that key using indexed types. Thanks a lot i appreciate the help <3.